# Regex with preg_replace in PHP

Tags: php, regex

It's a long time ago that I haven't played with PHP and regex and I'd like to find a regex that would do the following work.

My string contains :

```
<pre code="...">some piece of code</pre> other non code content <pre code="...">some piece of code</pre> other non code content...
```

The goal is to replace all the `<pre>code</pre> by`&

```
code
```

...`

Where `"code"` inside the `<pre>&</pre>` should also be escaped with `htmlspecialchars...`

I've already tried a few regex but didn't succeed.

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Could you include those regex you tried in your question?

Comment: "I've already tried a few regex but didn't succeed." --- so let's try together. Show what you've tried and explain why you tried it in that way

Comment: @Denis [FWIW](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182189/please-stop-linking-to-the-zalgo-anti-cthulhu-regex-rant)

Comment: @user2852559 hint: use `preg_replace_callback()` to match and apply `htmlspecialchars()` while adding some CSS.

Comment: ok sorry for the spam, you can delete this post. Really can't use this forum! Will see elsewhere, thanks to those who replied

Comment: @user2852559 It's a pain to spend 10 minutes on actually asking you what you have tried, fixing your question (because of formatting) and wait until you reply/fix it. It's also a bother for you since you mostly get comments that aren't getting you to a direct answer. So next time please spend some time on elaborating a good question: good formatting, show the code you have tried, show what doesn't work and the expected output. That way, we'll be all happy.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, using RegEx to parse HTML is a bad idea.
There are plenty of simple scenarios, where RegEx is enough to solve a particular problem, and that is great.

I would argue that in your case using RegEx is a bad idea, it will not cover all cases and it is likely insecure. You are possibly trying to prevent XSS vulnerabilities, and RegEx based solutions are always error-prone.

But for completeness sake:

```
preg_replace_callback(
    '/(<\\s*pre(?:\\s[^>]+)?>)(.*?)(<\\/\s*pre\s*>)/',
    function ($match) {
        return $match[1].htmlspecialchars($match[2]).$match[3];
    },
    $html
);
```

Comment: This isn't Java where you need to escape `\s`. Also there is no need to escape `<`

Comment: @HamZa I don't know why I thought `<` needs escaping. As for `\s`, I find it bad style to rely on dynamic behavior of backslash. After all, i I ever need to match literal `\s`, just escaping the backslash won't work, I need three backslashes: `\\\s`. When once escapes strictly, the cases are clear: `\\s` and `\\\\s`. But that's a matter of personal preference.